# Request.Form Vs Session MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, session-variables

I am using **Session** variables to store information. It works fine until some file like web.config or IIS itself is changed from outside. In my case, it usually happens on doing Jenkins. 
When that happens all the information stored in the session gets lost as a result I get logged out forcibly.

In order to cope this I am now planning to use **Request.Form** to hold all the required information instead. Therefore I want to ask the forum if Request.Form is safe in order to use it like Session Variables.

Comment: Using Request.Form in mvc sounds a bit dodgy and the data is going to go back and forth in every request. It all depends on what you want to store there. If it is an object, you should be able to serialize it before including it in a form. Another option for replacing Session is saving the information into cookies or using local storage so that the data don't need to be posted to server every time.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is Model View Controller right? Not using session is not a good idea, neither request.form. The best approach to write MVC application is creating a Model according to your needs and 'posting' or 'getting' from your controller. It's even more testable, maintainable and extensible then sessions and request.from.

Just for giving an example;

```
    public class YourController : Controller
{
    private readonly IEmailMessengerService _emailMessageService;
    private readonly IUnitOfWorkFactory _unitOfWorkFactory;

    // dependency injection 
    public YourController
        (IUnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWorkFactory,
            IEmailMessengerService emailMessageService)
    {
        _unitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory;
        _emailMessageService = emailMessageService;
    }


    // GET: YourController
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(YourViewModel model)
    {
        #region backend validation
        if (
            !GoogleReCAPTCHAHelper.Check(Request["g-recaptcha-response"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleReCAPTCHASecret"]))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "You have to confirm that you are not robot!");
            return View(model);
        }

        // do your validation
        #endregion

        // do your needs here. 
    }
}
```

The question is, do you really need to use Session? If you really want to store a global data, you can consider `cookies`, `localStorage` or `sessionStroge` that store at the client side.

Comment: I want to hold the information throughout the entire session (not ASPX session ;) ). So as per your suggestion and some research I think I can go with Cookies instead.

Comment: Yeah, you can even do CRUD operation on both server side and client side. You should definitely go for cookies :)

Comment: Now with the cookies i run into one problem , I cannot assign the object beside string, while I can do the same in Session Variables. Do we have any solution for this?

Comment: @DhirajDhakal, you need to serialize the object as text and then parse it back as object when retrieved. That's why things like TempData and Session are so handy, because you can store and retrieve objects easily. Perhaps you should find out more in depth why you're losing Session and how to prevent it.

Comment: @DhirajDhakal if you would like to store objects or viewModel etc, you need to consider converting your object to JSON. As derloopkat said, you need to serialize your object to json string then you can store it into Cookies. When you need that data, you need to deserialize it to the object. Good luck